# Docker Daemon for Windows

Tags: windows, docker, server

I want to explore Docker development targeting Windows containers.   I understand Microsoft has put out the Tech Preview for Server 2016, but am wondering if there are other options for Docker containers running on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

No, there are not (well, unless you consider [boot2docker](http://boot2docker.io/) an option). Original Docker containers are built upon [LXC](https://linuxcontainers.org/), which is a Linux technology. Microsoft had to implement some new APIs for Windows Server 2016 that Docker can wrap to make Windows Docker containers run on Windows Server 2016.

Comment: LXC was just one provider of what lies underneath all current containerization efforts on Linux: Namespaces + CGroups; for over a year the better option has been libcontainer nowadays known as runC.

Answer (score 0):

To develop Windows containers, you can do any of the following:

- [Run containers directly on Windows 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_10)
- Run a WS2016 VM on Windows 10 and develop with that
- [Run WS2016 bare metal or on Azure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/quick_start/quick_start_windows_server)